# Firestore doesn't throw an offline error for queries

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

On my website, I am trying to add error handling for when Firebase might be offline. So far I managed to get Firestore to throw an offline error only when I am fetching exactly one document. However, when I query for multiple documents, Firestore pretends as if nothing wrong happened and just returns an empty list.

This code below fetches only one document and will correctly throw a Firestore error if Firebase is offline/unreachable.

```
const getProjectEntry = async (projectEntryId: string) => {
 const doc = await db.collection('projectentries').doc(projectEntryId).get();
 if (doc.exists && doc) {
   return { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id } as IProjectEntry;
 }
 return null;
};
```

This code below fetches multiple documents and pretends as if everything is ok and returns an empty list when offline.

```
const getProjectEntries = async () => {
  const querySnapshot = (await db.collection('projectentries').get()).docs;
  return querySnapshot.map((doc) => {
    return { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id } as IProjectEntry;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default a `get()` call tries to get the data you request from the server, and then returns it from its cache if it can't reach the server.

In your first example, since you're requesting a specific document that likely doesn't exist in the local cache, that leads to to an error/

In the second example, it leads to a query against the local cache, which returns no results.

So the code is working as designed in both cases, although the behavior is different. If you want the server to fail when it can't reach the server, specify [`GetOptions` in the call to `get`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#get):

```
db.collection('projectentries').get({ source: 'server' })
```